# Where to get l2tp plugin for Network Manager in Centos 7

Tags: centos, networkmanager, vpn

I need to connect to the l2tp VPN of my company, but I cannot find the package NetworkManager-l2tp in repositories. I used to use it in Fedora, but I cannot find it in the repositories of Centos 7. I have enabled the EPEL repo, but still, the package is missing. I have installed some other VPN plugins for NetworkManager, but I cannot find the option for l2tp.

So, I'd like to know if there is some third part repositories where I can find this l2tp VPN plugin please. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NetworkManager-l2tp-1.0.4 has been pushed to the EPEL7 repository.

You can install it with:

```
sudo yum install NetworkManager-l2tp-gnome
```